# Accessing a file in ruby - differences

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

What is the different between the following statements?

```
#(not working)
File.exists?("path to file")

#(working)
::File.exists?("path to file")
```

I used above statements in Chef framework of Ruby.

Comment: Need to check full code.. share it

Comment: This question is actually very legitimate with respect to Chef. In Chef, `File` refers to `Chef::Resource::File`, whereas `::File` refers to the top-level Ruby `File` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is possible try to replicate your issue :

Not working :

```
class Foo< BasicObject
  def self.file_size
     File.size(__FILE__)
  end
end

p Foo.file_size # uninitialized constant Foo::File (NameError)
```

The reason is `File` class is available to the top level ( i.e. in the scope of the class `Object`) and inside any class which is a *direct*/ *indirect* subclass of `Object`. But `Foo` has no relation with `Object`, you wouldn't be able to access it inside `Foo`, if you don't tell it, from where `File` class ( or constant ) actually accessible.

Working :

```
class Foo< BasicObject
  def self.file_size
     ::File.size(__FILE__)
  end
end

p Foo.file_size # => 132
```

Although here also, `Foo` has no relation with `Object`, but we are explicitly ( by using `::` constant scope resolution operator ) telling Ruby that from where we are trying to access the `File` class ( *Remember class(s) are also constant in Ruby*) inside `Foo` class. Thus here is no objection from Ruby.

Check out if such situation is present in your code too.

Answer (score 7):

There is another constant named `File` in the scope where you are using `File.exists?("path to file")`. But when you use the `::` operator, you are telling ruby to find the `File` constant in `Object` (`Object::File`)

Comment: *There is another constant named `File` in the scope where you are using...* - How do you come to know this, there is another constant `File` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit because chef has some own ``File`` constants defined, like ``Chef::Provider::File``, and one of those constants is "hiding" the ``Object::File`` constant.

Comment: It's seeing that first one as a Chef Provider file like mentioned. Cookbook File extends this class as well

Answer (score -1):

On a side-note, File.exists? is deprecated - use File.exist?

According to maty, the question should be asked in this way:

"object, do you exist?"
"object.exist?"

Keep this in mind - yes, "if file exist" is not proper english,
but asking it that way would be wrong from the ruby object
point of view.

As for the leading :: - this refers to toplevel scope.

It is not often required, usually only when you have the same name
of a class or a module.